# Python - Split a time period into multiple time periods of fixed length

Tags: python, date, datetime

Given two dates, I would like to generate a list of dates with a fixed time length in between one another using *datetime*, starting from the later date.
For instance, given `01/01/2018` and `01/09/2018` and time interval of 2 months the output would be:

```
[01/01/2018, 01/03/2018, 01/05/2018, 01/07/2018, 01/09/2018]
```

For an interval of 3 months:

```
[01/03/2018, 01/06/2018, 01/09/2018]
```

I cannot just subtract months using the `.replace` method on a *datetime* object since going from a 31 days month to a 30 days month would return an error.

Comment: If you are happy to use pandas then see [pandas.interval_range](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.interval_range.html)

Comment: I would rather stick with datetime, but I will look into this if nothing else comes up thanks.

Comment: Read about [datetime.timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta)

Comment: The problem with timedelta is that I cannot move from one date to another in time steps bigger than weeks

Answer (score 3):

I think `relativedeleta` module can help you on this - `pip install python-dateutil`

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import *
import datetime
date1 = datetime.datetime.strptime('01/01/2018', "%d/%m/%Y").date()
date2 = datetime.datetime.strptime('01/09/2018', "%d/%m/%Y").date()
f = [(date1 + relativedelta(months=i)).strftime("%d/%m/%Y") for i in range(date1.month, date2.month,2)]
```

Result will be - ['01/02/2018', '01/04/2018', '01/06/2018', '01/08/2018']

Comment: Thank you, how would you amend your code if the time period was over a year? Since you are using the month of each date.

Comment: you can pass month difference init to range function - 
`date_diff = relativedelta(date2, date1)`
`month_diff = date1.month + date_diff.months * (date_diff.years+1)`

Answer (score 0):

You did specify *datetime*, but if you're interested,
a `time.localtime` object can be broken down like so:

```
import time

secSinceEpoch = time.time()
currentTime = time.localtime(secSinceEpoch)
month = currentTime.tm_mon
day = currentTime.tm_mday
year = currentTime.tm_year
hour = currentTime.tm_hour
min = currentTime.tm_min
sec = currentTime.tm_sec
```

From here you could perform operations on specific parts of the date/time...